# Create a 2d array Gameobject in unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

I'm having some trouble creating a 2D array game object.

I would write in Java

```
Gameobject[][] gameobjects= new Gameobject[x][y];
```

As far as I know, c# is based on Java and much works like in Java.  But I'm having some troubles when creating a 2D array gameobject because it shows me an error in the second dimension parameter

I couldn't find anything about my problem on YouTube, so I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

So, for your case...

```
Gameobject[,] gameobjects= new Gameobject[x,y];
```